# React Native Passing User Input Data to Component in Tab Bar IOS through Navigator

Tags: javascript, properties, react-native, tabbar, navigator

before anything, I'm a beginner in programming so I would really appreciate if anyone can provide me with a beginner-friendly explanation of my issue.

I am trying to pass user data from the initial 'date' input page into one component that is part of TabBarIOS. I tried to do this by passing props through navigator, because the input page navigates directly to the first component of the TabBarIOS. 
Here is my code:

```
class Details extends Component {
    constructor() {
    super();
    this.state = {
      date: new Date(),

  onDateChange( date ) {
    this.setState ({date: date});
  }

  navigate (){
  this.props.navigator.push({
    name: 'TabBar',
    component: TabBar,
    passProps: {date: this.date}

  })
}
```

I have the [DatePicker IOS code](https://facebook.github.io/react-native/docs/datepickerios.html) implemented here, so that the user's inputed date is rendered and returned to show that date like this; afterwards navigating to the TabBar component:

```
  <DatePickerIOS
      date={(this.state && this.state.date) || new Date()}
      onDateChange={(newDate) => {
        this.setState({date: newDate})
      }}
      mode={'date'}
      timeZoneOffsetInMinutes={-1 * new Date().getTimezoneOffset()} />
    </View>

 <View style = {styles.nameInput} value = {this.state.date}>
      <Text> {this.state.date.getDate()}/{this.state.date.getMonth()}/{this.state.date.getFullYear()}</Text>
      </View>

    <TouchableHighlight style = {styles.button} onPress = {() => this.navigate(date)}>
    <Text> Start </Text>
    </TouchableHighlight>
```

Afterwards, I try to do this into the TabBar component:

```
    <TabBarIOS.Item
      selected = {this.state.selectedTab === 'Home'}
      systemIcon = "history"
      onPress={() => {
        this.setState({
          selectedTab: 'Home',
        });
      }}>
    <Home date = {this.date}></Home>
   </TabBarIOS.Item>
```

The following is now the Home component:

```
class Home extends Component {
   render () {
     return (
       <Text> The date is {this.props.date} </Text>
        );
       }
      }
```

Can somebody explain to me what I am doing wrong here- if anybody needs more information to answer this question I can provide the necessary details.

Thank You

Answer (score 0):

after learning and using React Native for a period of time since this question has been posted, I resorted to the flux architecture for this specific problem.

I used the Redux framework to store the user inputed data and easily update its state whenever need arises. For instance, this date data can be changed by the user now easily using Redux, and it can be called between all my components.

In regards to passing props in general, I have used passProps within my navigator component like this, for instance:

```
navigate() {
    this.props.navigator.push({
    name: 'XYZ',
    component: XYZ,
    passProps: {
      ex1: this.state.ex2,
    },
}
```

And then call it in my following component like this:

```
<Text>{props.ex1}</Text>
```

Making sure to have this in my initial Navigator:

```
...route.passProps
```

Hope this could help anybody.
Let me know if you need further clarifications.